# Xcode is telling me to put in expected ',' separator

Tags: xcode, separator

xcode is telling me to put in expected ',' separator. Below is my code. even when i put in what Xcode tells me I still get an error. Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

```
        } else {

            if let p = placemarks?[0] {

                var subThoroughfare:String = ""

                if (p.throughfare != nil {

                    subThoroughfare = p.subThoroughfare

            } // there are telling me to put this ',' here


                self.addressLabel.text = "\(subThoroughfare) \(p.thoroughfare) \n \(p.subLocality) \n \(p.subAdministrativeArea) \n \(p.postalCode) \n \(p.country)"

                } // xcode is telling me to put this ',' here

        } // xcode is telling me to put this ',' here            



    })
```

Comment: Show the surrounding code, such as the `if` that the first `else` belongs to and whatever the closing parenthesis on the last line matches. The syntax error is probably not in the code you showed but something before then that confused the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this portion of your code and check if it still shows the error:

```
if (p.throughfare != nil) {  
  subThoroughfare = p.subThoroughfare
}
```

If it still show the error please show the if part also in your code it will help in understanding the full code as there look like extra bracket at end also